# Check the query efficiency

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this below SQL query that I want to get an opinion on whether I can improve it using Temp Tables or something else or is this good enough? So basically I am just feeding the result set from inner query to the outer one.

```
SELECT S.SolutionID
    ,S.SolutionName
    ,S.Enabled
FROM dbo.Solution S
WHERE s.SolutionID IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT sf.SolutionID
        FROM dbo.SolutionToFeature sf
        WHERE sf.SolutionToFeatureID IN (
                SELECT sfg.SolutionToFeatureID
                FROM dbo.SolutionFeatureToUsergroup SFG
                WHERE sfg.UsergroupID IN (
                        SELECT UG.UsergroupID
                        FROM dbo.Usergroup UG
                        WHERE ug.SiteID = @SiteID
                        )
                )
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to depend largely on the indexes you have on those tables.  Since you are only selecting data out of the Solution table, you can put everything else in an exists clause, do some proper joins, and it should perform better.

The exists clause will allow you to remove the distinct you have on the SolutionToFeature table.  Distinct will cause a performance hit because it is basically creating a temp table behind the scenes to do the comparison on whether or not the record is unique against the rest of the result set.  You take a pretty big hit as your tables grow.

It will look something similar to what I have below, but without sample data or anything I can't tell if it's exactly right.

```
Select S.SolutionID, S.SolutionName, S.Enabled
From dbo.Solutin S
Where Exists    ( 
                select 1 
                from dbo.SolutionToFeature sf
                Inner Join dbo.SolutionToFeatureTousergroup SFG on sf.SolutionToFeatureID = SFG.SolutionToFeatureID
                Inner Join dbo.UserGroup UG on sfg.UserGroupID = UG.UserGroupID
                Where S.SolutionID = sf.SolutionID
                and UG.SiteID = @SiteID
                )
```

Comment: its showing me a syntax error on this line  from dbo.SolutionToFeature sf on S.SolutionID = sf.SolutionID saying incorrect syntax near 'on'

Comment: well my original query gives me 218 rows and this new query gives me 33

Comment: sorry the new query gives me 218 and my original query gives me 33.

Comment: I did a manual running of the query step by step directly on the tables and it also gives me 33 results so this Join query is not working for me.

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the query with the proper syntax. The S.SolutionID = sf.SolutionID should have been in the where clause of the exists statement.  That will join it back to your main select statement.

Comment: @user505210 If the updated statement still does not work.  Could you try creating a sqlfiddle so that I can see what else might be missing?